# How to create an instance in java based on specific input? Implementation of Singleton pattern

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have a Crypto Class.

```
public class Crypto{

    // This method returns the instance of Crypto class for the key.
    // If instance for key hasn't been created a new instance is created.
    // If already created for key the same instance is returned. 
    public static Crypto getInstance(String key){

    }

}
```

How do I implement this pattern? I mean this is singleton design pattern but different instances for different keys and where do I save the instance?

Comment: Use an enum. You can have multiple singleton instances.

Comment: Does it need to be thread-safe? Is the key dynamic or is it fixed?

Comment: this is not the Singleton pattern. In order for it to be, that method has to be static, and there has to be a static instance of that class there.

Comment: Edited to make the method static. But still he doesn't require the singleton pattern, he needs multiple instances of the same class, one for each unique key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a map :

```
    Class Crypto{
       Map<String,Crypto> map = new HashMap<String,Crypto>();
       private Crypto(){
       }
       public static Crypto getInstance(String key){
          if(map.contains(key)){
            return map.get(key);
          }
          else{
            // switch on the key and create your Cryptos
            map.put(key,new Crypto();
          }
          return map.get(key);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good, made some edits to make it simpler and the map should be static as well. Also depends if it needs to be used in a multi-threaded environment as well, not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the [multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern). This is a simple example for an implicit synchronized version:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Multiton {

    private static final class MultitonHolder {

        static final Map<String, Multiton> INSTANCES = new HashMap<>();

        static {
            INSTANCES.put("key-1", new Multiton());
            INSTANCES.put("key-2", new Multiton());
            INSTANCES.put("key-3", new Multiton());
            INSTANCES.put("key-4", new Multiton());
            INSTANCES.put("key-5", new Multiton());
        }

    }

    private Multiton() {}

    public static Multiton getInstance(final String key) {
        return MultitonHolder.INSTANCES.get(key);
    }

}
```

Example with additional fields:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Multiton {

    private static class MultitonHolder {

        static final Map<String, Multiton> INSTANCES = new HashMap<>();

        static {
            INSTANCES.put("key-1", new Multiton(1));
            INSTANCES.put("key-2", new Multiton(2));

            final Multiton multiton3 = new Multiton(3);

            multiton3.setAnotherField(3);
            INSTANCES.put("key-3", multiton3);

            final Multiton multiton4 = new Multiton(4);

            multiton3.setAnotherField(4);
            INSTANCES.put("key-4", multiton4);
        }

    }

    private final int someField;

    private int anotherField;

    private Multiton(final int someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    public static Multiton getInstance(final String key) {
        return MultitonHolder.INSTANCES.get(key);
    }

    public int getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    private void setAnotherField(final int anotherField) {
        this.anotherField = anotherField;
    }

    public int getAnotherField() {
        return anotherField;
    }

}
```

Comment: why is getInstance method static? - ?
Why Constructor private? - So that it can be initialized in the same class

Comment: Did you understand the singleton/multiton concept? You don't want that instances of your class are created elsewhere. Thus you make the constructor private. Since you can never create instances on your own, you can only call 'class methods' of this class. And if you want to work with your singleton class, you need a way to obtain an instance.

Comment: Yes, I got it. One more question. Suppose this class has a field which could be different for each instance, how do I link it with Multiton object?

Comment: The instances are created in the `static` block of the `MultitonHolder`. You can do there whatever you want. For example add an argument to the `Multiton` constructor that sets this field and pass the actual value when you create the instance. You can also use setter methods. I have added an example for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steffen. All this makes sense now, but how do I test it?

Comment: What do you mean with _How do I test it_?

Answer (score -2):

Similar with the above examples

```
public class Crypto {
    private ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static Crypto uniqInstance;

    private Crypto() {

    }

    public static Crypto getInstance(){
        if (uniqInstance==null){
            synchronized (Crypto.class){
                if(uniqInstance==null){
                    uniqInstance = new Crypto();
                }
            }
        }
        return uniqInstance;
    }

    public void addKey(String key){
        this.keyList.add(key);
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s="";
        for(String str:keyList){
            s+=str+" ";
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

I tested it with the following:

```
public class CryptoApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Crypto crypto;

        crypto = Crypto.getInstance();
        crypto.addKey("my123");
        crypto.addKey("my456");
        System.out.println(crypto);

        Crypto crypto2;
        crypto2 = Crypto.getInstance();crypto2.addKey("my789");System.out.println(crypto2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why people downvoted this answer? I am yet to implemented it.